# Rails' collection_select helper method and the "Create item" option at the end

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to add an `<option>` at the end of a `<select>` created with the `collection_select` helper method?

Right now I have

```
f.collection_select(:category_id , @categories, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Please select a category'})
```

which generates

```
<select id="product_category_id" name="product[category_id]">
  <option value="">Please select a category</option>
  <option value="7">category one</option>
  <option value="8">category 2</option>
</select>
```

and what I would like is

```
<select id="product_category_id" name="product[category_id]">
  <option value="">Please select a category</option>
  <option value="7">category one</option>
  <option value="8">category 2</option>
  <option value="new">..or create a new one</option>
</select>
```

Is this possible or should I just loop through the collection and generate the options manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should probably use `select` instead.

Like so:

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } + [ [ 'Or create a new one', 'new' ] ], {:include_blank => 'Please select a category'})
```

Good luck!

Comment: umm.. this creates 2 extra options, both with name equal with value, "Or create a new one" and "new"

Comment: I also tried with a hash instead of an array, Hash["name", "create a new one", "id", "new"], but I get a "can't convert Hash into Array".. figures..

Comment: so.. this would do, but, any ideas on how to set a value different than the text inside the option?

Answer (score 3):

Agreed on the short answer No and long answer " Be Crafty ", but here's what I just did which I think is simpler than either of these two solutions and worked for me:

Wrap the next line inside erb tags i.e. `<%=` and `%>`:

```
f.collection_select :advertisement_group_id, AdvertisementGroup.find(:all, :order => "name DESC") << AdvertisementGroup.new(:name => "New Group"), :id, :name, :include_blank => true
```

Just create a new object with `.new` and pass in whatever text you want displayed along with `:include_blank => true`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Sure, but you have to be crafty.

- Create a class like so:

  ```
  class New_option_placeholder
    def id 
      "new"
    end

    def name
      "...or create a new one"
    end
  end
  ```
- Instead of passing `@categories`, pass `@categories+New_option_placeholder.new`

If (as indicated by the comments) you're looking for something terser you could `require "ostruct"` and then pass `@categories + [OpenStruct.new(:id => 'new',:name => '...or create a new one')]` to accomplish essentially the same this.

Comment: This would probably work, but it's too much of a workaround so I think I'll go for Gdeglin's solution. +1 still 'cause it does what I wanted

Comment: I think by the time you get Gdeglin's solution working you'll have something with more moving parts than this.  If you're just looking for a one-line version I'll add one...

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment otherwise I'd add this to the answer above.

To get the option->value "new","or create a new one".. instead of

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } + ['Or create a new one','new'], {:include_blank => 'Please select a category'})
```

do

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } + [['Or create a new one','new']], {:include_blank => 'Please select a category'})
```

note the extra [] around the options.  This makes the array work as an option,value pair