# Creating new record through collection_select rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, collection-select

I am a newbie in ROR and I want to create new record from collection_select if the existing collection does not have the record needed 
I tried this solution but it doesn't work for me 
[Rails' collection_select helper method and the "Create item" option at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699165/rails-collection-select-helper-method-and-the-create-item-option-at-the-end)
May be i need to add something to my create controller method